# How to use a microSD card reader with SCK instead of CLK?

Tags: sd-card

I've bought this microSD reader/writer: http://www.ebay.com/itm/131132034753

I've found only one tutorial, where the pins are similar to my pins, but in the example there is a CLK instead of SCK: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/microsd-shield-and-sd-breakout-hookup-guide

The pins on my MicroSD reader are:

- CS
- SCK
- MOSI
- MISO
- VCC
- GND

Comment: SCK is actually a clock signal. So basically, they are the same thing here.

Answer (score 11):

SCK stands for **S**PI **C**loc**K**

CLK stands for SPI **CL**oc**K**

Two different acronyms for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's common practice for speakers/writers to use the generic term: "clock" (CLK) for various different situations. This clearly being a *serial* interface we don't need to specifically say **S**erial clo**CK** each time the signal mentioned, as it's more of a mouthful than saying "clock".

In this case consider "CLK" and "SCK" as fully interchangeable.